# Macro dulicate in macros document

Tags: api, revit-api

Macros image

[image: 1]

Could you help me please ?
I have prolem with macros document in central file . It have dulicate to much and I dont know why.
How can i remove it with API or different Macro .

Comment: Also discussed in the Revit API discussion forum thread on [Macros duplicate in central file](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/macros-dulicate-in-central-file/m-p/11624042)

Answer (score 0):

The Revit API provides a [`MacroManager` class](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/49eb4b8a-ae13-95e7-fef4-11347bbb67d3.htm) with a [`RemoveModule` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/c22a452e-578c-d468-e041-e70fd72cc78f.htm). You could use that to delete the entire module. Or, to remove a single macro, you can use the [`RemoveMacro` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/66e8c11a-60fc-3046-de82-55020a2ceb3f.htm).